# Getting "clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'" when trying to compile OpenMP using gcc

Tags: c, macos, gcc, openmp

I installed the latest version of gcc using homebrew in order to get OpenMP support, however, that is what is happening:

```
Sergios-MacBook:~ sergio$ gcc -fopenmp test.c -o test
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
```

I know that clang is the default compiler in the command line tools I have installed but I don't know what is happening and how to fix it.

If this could be of any use, I tried checking the location of gcc and got the following:

```
Sergios-MacBook:~ sergio$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

I don't know if by default gcc is there and it is still linked to the system default one which doesn't support OpenMP

Comment: no I never heard of it,  I will try now

Comment: just tried, still the same error.

Comment: I remember solving this pretty easily, can you tell me what do you have in $PATH?

Comment: here is what I have in $PATH: `/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Users/sergio/opt/anaconda3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`

Comment: Okey can you try adding  /usr/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin: to the beginning of the PATH

Comment: Do you want to make it work with gcc or it is good as it is?